# How to download wine and install to many computers

Tags: 13.10, wine, software-installation

I'm an ICT tutor at a school and we have moved from windows to ubuntu.

I need to download wine and install MS Office for the students for their office work - we cannot use open office for their practicals for now. We have a limitation in terms of bandwidth, so our machines are restricted in terms of downloads. How can I download a single package of wine and then install it to several computers seeing we have slow and limited internet.

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu so step by step instructions would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Will this be the only case where you need to download a package **once** and install it  on all students' computers?

- What about keeping the machines updated?
- What if other packages turn out to be necessary in the course?

I can't imagine that you - as a tutor - want to fiddle around with a memory stick all the time.

Since multiple downloads are out of question, you'll have to find a way achieve the following:

- download necessary packages (and updates/fixes) **once** to the tutor's computer, using the recommended way, that is from a repository with `ap-get`, the **SoftwareCenter** or **synaptic**
- use your (the tutor's) computer as the **local repository** for the installation of packages on the students' computers via the **local network**.

You might want to have a look at the general [AptGet How-To](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto?action=show&redirect=AptGetHowto) and [AptProxy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptProxy) for possible directions.

Answer (score 0):

You can download wine Ubuntu install from [winehq](http://www.winehq.org/download) and you can install it with the command `dpkg -i "path to file"`.

Comment: *protip* While your answer satisfies installing the wine package, it can be further expanded to include the mscore-ttf packages and more that are required to run a successful wine installation.

Comment: It would be much better if you gave a 'step-by-step' answer and not just a `...with a command dpkg -i "path to file"`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. One main factor is that we have very limited Internet connections so the need to have software is once off - i know we need all those updates, but as it stands we could do without them. As Avatar Parto said it would be kind of u if you were to give me a step by step approach - im also new to Ubuntu so some of things may be quite difficult to deal with...